# How to set a maximum execution time in JSP/Servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I would like to set a time limit for script execution. In PHP I use "set_time_limit". How can I do this in JSP?

Answer (score 2):

I have to disappoint you - there is no such setting. In JSP it is hardly feasible, when using servlets (especially 3.0) you have some options. However all of them require running your logic in a separate thread.

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663732) here, it is about Spring MVC, but it explains the general concept.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code you want to execute inside of java Runnable, then use ExecutorService to set a timeout for that task.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Answer (score 0):

This should be a setting of your servlet container. In tomcat you can configure these on the connector - [see here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html) (look for 'timeout'). (Also [see here](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/timeouts.html))